# YA short horror story from the 90's? Student obsessed with teacher kills herself Cover art had a ghostly looking girl wearing fish necklace

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, horror

I'm pretty sure the girl's name was Fern, and she becomes obsessed with her teacher. When he dies (I believe he drowns) she kills herself and haunts her best friend by tapping on her window. There's a fish (or at least I'm fairly certain it was a fish) necklace involved and the girls hide notes to each other in a tree hollow.

I would have read it in around 2000 and I don't think it was that old then, so I'm guessing the book was published in the mid to late 90's.

I'd love help finding this book! If anyone could even point me in the direction of the publisher.

I'm fairly sure there were a series of these short horror stories from the same publisher with different authors - I seem to recall one about a clique of vampires maybe at a high school.

Comment: Hi and welcome to scifi.se! Maybe you could provide a bit more information. When did you read the story? Was it older then or brand-new? Was it a magazine or a book, harcover or softcover? Any recollections of the cover art? Anything you can remember helps. And please don't leave it as comment, but edit it into your question, so everyone can see without reading the comments.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice, I've edited it a bit. Hopefully it helps :)

Comment: The bit with the messages hidden in the tree sounds familiar, but I can't say from where...

Answer (score 7):

[*The Mouth*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6864515-the-mouth) by Carmel Bird

[image: Book cover - The Mouth]
You can see the fish on the front cover.

> Jade knows that her best friend, Fern, has died. Yet she can hear Fern
> tapping on the window every night - what is Fern's ghost trying to
> tell her?

It's part of the [After Dark](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pubseries.cgi?799) series.